# Run Services in Background Android New Versions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, process

I want to display a Toast message when the screen unlocks, saying "screen is open." This functionality is currently working when the app is open, but I want it to run as a background service. This means that even when the app is closed or removed from recent tabs, it should still work when the screen unlocks, displaying the message that the screen is unlocked.

Please let me know if you need further assistance or if you have specific questions about implementing this functionality.
Here is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.ached.dalima;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button unlockButton;
    private ScreenUnlockReceiver screenUnlockReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        unlockButton = findViewById(R.id.unlockButton);
        Intent ServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ScreenUnlockService.class);
        startService(ServiceIntent);

        unlockButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This is an example of handling a button click in your MainActivity
                showToast("Unlock button clicked!");
            }
        });
        screenUnlockReceiver = new ScreenUnlockReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerScreenUnlockReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterScreenUnlockReceiver();
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    class ScreenUnlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                showToast("Screen is open!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void registerScreenUnlockReceiver() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        registerReceiver(screenUnlockReceiver, filter);
    }

    // Unregister the ScreenUnlockReceiver
    private void unregisterScreenUnlockReceiver() {
        unregisterReceiver(screenUnlockReceiver);
    }
}
```

Below is ScreenUnlockService.java

```
package com.ached.dalima;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class ScreenUnlockService extends Service {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Channel";
    private Handler handler;
    private ScreenUnlockReceiver screenUnlockReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        screenUnlockReceiver = new ScreenUnlockReceiver();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel();
        }

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Audio Service")
                .setContentText("Playing audio in the background")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .build();

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    class ScreenUnlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                showToast("Screen is open here!");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Below is Receiver file

```
package com.ached.dalima;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ScreenUnlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            // Screen unlock event detected
            // You can perform actions here when the screen is unlocked.
        }
    }
}
```

Below is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ached.dalima"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DaLima"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <receiver
            android:name=".ScreenUnlockReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".AudioService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".ScreenUnlockService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

***The issue is that I want the app to run in the background and display Toast messages even after it's removed from the recent apps list.***